# Propagate Request context to coroutines

Tags: spring, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm using Spring 6 with Koltin 1.8 (and Java 19 JVM). Kotlin coroutines 1.6.4. I have my own implementation of `AuditorAware` in my own library. This class basically gets the income request, gets the token, decodes it and extracts the e-mail from it.
Something like:

```
@Component
class MyCustomAuditorAware(...): AuditorAware<String> {
    val request = (RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() as ServletRequestAttributes).request
    // other irrelevant code
}
```

Then I have a couple of projects that use this library. Both are using the same configuration as above.
The problem occurs when trying to propagate the `RequestContextHolder` using coroutines (suspend functions). Since it is switching contexts, it simply loses the request data. One of the projects is working, and I couldn't figure out why.
The other isn't.

I have tried setting the

```
DispatcherServlet.setThreadContextInheritable(true)
```

but at some point it recycles the object and child threads cannot access the data.

How can I avoid this loss when switching contexts?

**EDIT**: also tried to implement [this](https://blog.jdriven.com/2021/07/propagating-the-spring-securitycontext-to-your-kotlin-coroutines/), adapting it to `RequestContextHolder` but couldn't make it.

Providing the controller code:

```
class MyController(private myUseCase: MyUseCase) {
    /* swagger annotations and some variables declaration */

    suspend fun executeUseCase(/* irrelevant parameters*/) = 
        runBlocking { myUseCase.run(/*parameters*/) }
}
```

Right now is using `runBlocking`, which generates a coroutine with `Dispatcher.Unconfined`. But the idea is to remove it.

Comment: So, you are using Spring MVC, which is essantially thread bound. Maybe it would be easier with Webflux, which uses another context mechanism, that, I think, would be more compatible with coroutines (mostly because Spring provides an interoperability lib between reactor/webflux and coroutines). But, if you require MVC/threadlocal based information, can you provide an example of how you create your coroutine context ? Without it, it is difficult to analyze the problem (because context loss, I think, mostly depends on what information you pass to the coroutinecontext from your request thread).

Comment: @amanin Thanks, I need to keep using MVC right now (it is in the roadmap to change it to use Webflux, but this has more priority).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `fun executeUseCase() = runBlocking { ... }` instead ? Normally, *runBlocking* is made to bind coroutines with the "blocking world", and therefore, it should not be called from coroutine/suspend function.

Comment: @amanin it should be suspend. `runBlocking` should be removed and replaced by actual `CoroutineScope`.

Comment: I didn't understand the problem, but maybe `ThreadLocal` object is relevant